# Fast, efficient inter-processing messaging

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I'm working on a system which consists of a chain of data transformation components. Each of these components performs a very simple task on an object before passing it on to the next component in the chain. Each of these components runs as a Windows Service. I've designed the system in this way to improve maintenance and aid future extensibility.

At the moment, I'm passing these objects between the components using message queuing, but this is fast becoming a concern. There are likely to be tens of services all continually reading from and writing to message queues. As I understand, all messages are serialized and written to disk which, in my system where the throughput will be very fast, seems very wasteful.

Are there any other established systems which I could use for inter-process communication which avoids the overhead of continual disk reads and writes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need guaranteed reliable or transactional messaging you should be able to improve performance significantly in `System.Messaging` by setting your [Message.Recoverable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.recoverable.aspx) properties to `false`.  Incidentally by default this is already false so your assumption about disk usage may not be correct, assuming the original solution does use MSMQ.

> Type: System.Boolean
>
> true if delivery of the message is guaranteed (through saving the message to disk while en 
>   route); false if delivery is not assured. The default is false.

The **best** solution depends on your service's requirements.  You may be able to use this, or you might need some extremely low latency service bus (usually a commercial product), or something in between that you build yourself.

Comment: I'm using the defaults, so this will be False in my current system.

Comment: Then what makes you think everything is getting written to disk?

Comment: An assumption. I actually began developing a message queue implementation that stores so many objects in memory before deciding to write them to disk (e.g. if the 'destination' service goes offline). The objects are sent to the 'server' via a named pipe from the source, and read by the destination via another named pipe. This was, on average, 3x faster that MSMQ. However, I don't like reinventing the wheel unless I have to, so I was hoping for an existing solution if there is one.

Comment: I am sure that a custom, single protocol solution will perform faster, but you may find that you need more and more of the ready-made MSMQ function, and as you add this it's harder to keep it fast - if you are sure that this architecture works for you now and in the future, I would go with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

[ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is a memory only message queue implementation.